# String refernce is held in heap after sql execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, r2dbc

Lately I have encountered a really strange memory leak.
I would appreciate if someone helps me resolve it.

```
public Mono<Boolean> insertOrders(List<ClientOrder> orders) {
    if (orders.isEmpty()) {
      return Mono.just(true);
    } else {
      var sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder().append(OrderQueries.INSERT_ORDERS_START);
      for (var i = 0; i < orders.size(); i++) {
        var order = orders.get(i);
        sqlBuilder.append(String.format(
          OrderQueries.INSERT_ORDERS_PARAMS,
          order.getUserId(),
          order.getUserName(),
          order.getCustomerEmail(),
          order.getCustomerMobile(),
          order.getAmount(),
          order.getCreateDate(),
          order.getStatusChangeDate(),
          i == orders.size() - 1 ? ';' : ','
        ));
      }
      return this.databaseClient.sql(sqlBuilder.toString()).fetch().rowsUpdated()
        .doOnError(log::error)
        .map(rows -> rows == orders.size());
    }
  }
```

And when i perform a heapdump I can see that the reference to the string of the query is stored and the sql queries are never cleared by the GC. [image: HEAP DUMP]

Comment: It's in a Spring cache. If you'd like it not to be, you'll have to investigate your Spring configuration to see if there's a way not to cache this.

Comment: Besides that, `String.format(…)` can not sanitize input for SQL statements. If you do not want to meet [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) one day, you should drop that code and use a `PreparedStatement` (or something this framework offers atop of that).

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the proposition.  I am always using the prepared statement, but int this case r2dbc connection prepared statement is not updating the table in batch. So this is a workaround. and also the data is used from external API . which is reliable. thats not a user input to think about SQL injections.

Comment: Even if the data comes “from external API”, it doesn’t preclude that, e.g. data like a user name comes from a user. And if that other system was reliable enough to handle unusual strings correctly, it especially means that you must be prepared for getting those strings exactly as the user provided them.

Comment: I totally agree with you and understand what you are talking about. But I have tried the prepared statement with the update by R2DBC this insert (55k rows )  was taking about 30 minutes. Can you suggest a solution to that delay ? because going with plain string is taking in this case just about 2 minutes.

Comment: And the next problem would be to disable caching of queries and parameters for the preparedStatement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  OrderDao(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
    this.databaseClientNamed = DatabaseClient.builder().connectionFactory(connectionFactory).namedParameters(true).build();
    this.databaseClient = DatabaseClient.builder().connectionFactory(connectionFactory).namedParameters(false).build();
  }
```

As @ControlAltDel has mentioned the problem was with spring caching the sql statements. So as I am not using the prepared statement for this particular case and the query is very big 55K inserts. The workaround in that particular case was using another database client without namedParamenters (which was caching the result) I don't reccomend this solution to anyone. But this would be good for anyone that finds out some sql queries in Heap.
NamedParameterExpander is caching everything you execute.